# List contacts with phone numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I'd like to fetch (in iOS using Objective-C) only the contacts that have a phone number, but how can I do that? I'm trying to form the predicate as in the code below, but obviously that doesn't work.

```
contacts = [contactStore unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumbers <> nil"] keysToFetch:KEYS error:nil];
```

So, what is the correct way of doing this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: I tried what I wrote in the code snipplet.

Comment: @Eir try it my code for fetch contact list  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719037/list-contacts-with-phone-numbers/41720394#41720394

Comment: Did you try below answer and get you the solution?

Comment: I help you Eir.Tell what do you want exactly?

Comment: I want to filter out the contacts with no phone numbers, but through the request, not after I've fetched them. I don't see such solutions, until now. Maybe that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering out the contacts that don't have a phone number (or some other property) is not possible. In the docs we read:

> CNContact Predicates
>
> Predicates to match contacts. **You can only use these predicates**
>   with CNContactStore and CNContactFetchRequest.
>
> - predicateForContactsMatchingName: Returns a predicate to find the contacts matching the specified name.
> - predicateForContactsWithIdentifiers: Returns a predicate to find the contacts matching the specified identifiers.
> - predicateForContactsInGroupWithIdentifier: Returns a predicate to find the contacts that are members in the specified group.
> - predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier: Returns a predicate to find the contacts in the specified container.

And additionally:

> Compound predicates are not supported.

So, the only way to do the filtering would be to omit adding to the result array the contacts with no phone numbers. That could be done, for example, in the block of the `enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>


 CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
            CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keys];
            request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrderGivenName;
            request.unifyResults = YES;
            NSError *error;

            __block NSString* email;

            BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&error usingBlock:^(CNContact * __nonnull contact, BOOL * __nonnull stop)
                            {
                                if (error) {
                                    NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
                                } else {
                                    NSString *fullName;
                                    NSString* phone;

                                    //                    for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                                    DeviceContact *aContact = [DeviceContact new];

                                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                                    NSString *firstName = contact.givenName;
                                    NSString *lastName = contact.familyName;

                                    if (lastName == nil) {
                                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                                    }

                                    if ([firstName trim].length > 0) {
                                        aContact.nameForSorting = firstName; // 141116
                                    }else if ([lastName trim].length>0 && aContact.nameForSorting.length<=0) {
                                        aContact.nameForSorting = lastName; // 141116
                                    }

                                    aContact.name = fullName;


                                    if (contact.phoneNumbers!=nil && [contact.phoneNumbers count]>0) {
                                        for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                                            phone =  [CommonUtils removeAllSpecialCharactersFromPhoneNumber:[label.value stringValue]];
                                            if ([phone length] > 0) {
                                                [aContact.phoneNumber addObject:phone];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    ////Get all E-Mail addresses from contacts
                                    /// if ([CommonUtils checkIsNullObject:[contact emailAddresses]] && [[contact emailAddresses] count]>0) {
                                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.emailAddresses) {
                                        email = label.value;
                                        if ([email length] > 0)
                                        {
                                            [aContact.email addObject:email];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // }

                                    // 141116
                                    if ([aContact.name trim].length <= 0) {
                                        if (aContact.email.count>0) {
                                            aContact.name = [aContact.email objectAtIndex:0];
                                        }else if (aContact.phoneNumber.count>0){
                                            aContact.name = [aContact.phoneNumber objectAtIndex:0];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if ([aContact.nameForSorting trim].length <= 0){
                                        if (aContact.email.count>0) {
                                            aContact.nameForSorting = [aContact.email objectAtIndex:0];
                                        }else if (aContact.phoneNumber.count>0){
                                            aContact.nameForSorting = [aContact.phoneNumber objectAtIndex:0];
                                        }
                                    }

                                    [self.arrAllContacts addObject:aContact];
                                }

                            }];

            if(success){

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [CommonUtils hideLoader];

                    completionhandler(self.arrAllContacts);
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // [CommonUtils showAlertMessageWithMessage:@"fdfdggfsgfdgfd" withDelegate:self withCancelTitle:OKAY isOtherButton:NO withOtherButtonTitle:nil withTag:0];
            [CommonUtils hideLoader];

        }
    }];
```

Comment: I added a plus to this solution because it is nice and clean. However, I'm not marking it as an accepted answer because I was asking for a way to rule out the phoneless contacts at fetch time, when making the request. Maybe that is not possible. If so, that would be the correct answer to my question.

Comment: Despite the fact that in your code, in the end results you end up having also the contacts with no phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use following method and import

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h> 


-(void)contactsDetailsFromPhoneContactBook{
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactGivenNameKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            } else {
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;
                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    }
                    else{
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }
                    [self.contactsArray addObject:fullName];

                    NSLog(@"working or not %@",self.contactsArray);
                }

            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Well, this seems to get all contacts, regardless of whether they have a phone number or not.